# Unable to redirect in symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

my php redirects dont seem to be working when i apply this redirect to my action :

```
 $statement->prepare("UPDATE sample.booking_appt SET booking_date = ?, 
  booking_time = ? where user_id = ? and booking_id = ?");
    $statement->bind_param('ssii',$date,$time,$user_id,$booking_id);
    $statement->execute();
    return  $this->redirectToRoute('operations_view',array('id'=>$id));

error message is : Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/calendar" 
as such route does not exist.
```

the calendar route exists in the routing.yml file and it has been registered as well. any advice on how to use the redirects in symfony would be great.

Comment: The code you posted does not really match your error message.  Somewhere you are trying to generate a route with a name of '/calendar' instead of 'calendar'

Comment: Why is symfony trying to generate a route named `/calendar` when you are sending to a route named `operations_vew`? I think that's the first step to help track down the problem.

Comment: /calendar is the name of the view and the action, and the route path is operations view

Comment: I think you have those backwards.

Comment: i have it, i was missing parameters so as my final solution :                                           return  $this->redirectToRoute('operations_view',array('id'=>$user_id));

Answer (score 0):

final solution is :

```
 return  $this->redirectToRoute('operations_view',array('id'=>$user_id));
```

operations_view is the name of the route and my naming is incorrect, thanks everyone